# show double id in click function

Tags: jquery

Hi I have 2 click function when the second element is clicked the console show duplicate id if I move console.log to the first click it show one log. How to  resolve this problem.I want to click 2 modal and return without duplicate "id".Thank you

```
function clickForDelete(){
        $('.information').click(function(event){               
            var id = this.id;
            $('#deleteItem').click(function(event){
                console.log(id);
                deleteItem(id);
            });
            $('#checkInfo').click(function(event){
                info(id);
            });
        });
    }
```

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7bso.png)

[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbuvS.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is called "bubbling" and it works firing the events through the above functions. So you can stop it with `stopPropagation()`

```
function clickForDelete(){
    $('.information').click(function(event){               
        var id = this.id;
        $('#deleteItem').click(function(event){
            console.log(id);
            deleteItem(id);
            event.stopPropagation(); // see here;
        });
        $('#checkInfo').click(function(event){
            info(id);
            event.stopPropagation(); // and here;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to explain better your problem. This should work

Comment: I call ajax by method get.when it done I have some data and then I use it to create new element class then I use settimeout(clickForDelete,100); my explain so bad so sorry

Comment: if I am not use settimeout I can not click new element.Have you another way to make this better

Comment: Share your ajax code, the problem is in asynchronous calls, as well as the bubbling that I'm explaining here

Answer (score 0):

this is old  code. my current project I use json but it is in my computer at office

```js
$(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                    daysOfWeekDisabled: [-1, 8],
                    showTodayButton: true,
                });

                //Select current time in DB
                   addDate = $('#datetxt').val();
                   checkDate(addDate);
                function checkDate(addDate){
                   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        var bgColor;
                        var M = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        //console.log(M);
                        if(M == ""){
                            //console.log("เข้าเคลีย");
                            clearTable();
                        }
                        var departmentName = M.split(" ");
                        console.log(departmentName);
                        //console.log(departmentName);
                        for(var i = 0; i<departmentName.length;i++){
                            if(departmentName[roomNumber] != undefined && departmentName[roomNumber] != "" || departmentName[departName] != undefined && departmentName[departName] != "" || departmentName[time] != undefined && departmentName[time] != "" || departmentName[thead] != undefined && departmentName[thead] != "" || 
                                departmentName[amPeople] != undefined && departmentName[amPeople] != "" || departmentName[baverage] != undefined && departmentName[baverage] != "" ||
                                departmentName[foodNum] != undefined && departmentName[foodNum] != "" || departmentName[mealNum] != undefined && departmentName[mealNum] != ""){
                                var slr = selectRoom(departmentName[roomNumber]);                               
                                var fcr = fillColorInRoom(departmentName[departName]);                               
                                var cti = changeTimeToInt(departmentName[time]);          
                                //console.log(departmentName[checkDates]);            
                                selectValueFromDB(slr,fcr,cti,departmentName[departName],departmentName[time],departmentName[thead],departmentName[amPeople],departmentName[baverage],departmentName[foodNum],departmentName[mealNum]);
                                roomNumber = roomNumber + 10;
                                departName = departName + 10;                               
                                time = time +10;
                                thead = thead +10;
                                amPeople = amPeople +10;
                                baverage = baverage +10;
                                foodNum = foodNum +10;
                                mealNum = mealNum +10;
                                checkDates = checkDates +10;
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","select.php?q="+addDate,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                    }
```